# Are the non-empty finite bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ complete with respect to the Hausdorff metric?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, hausdorff-measure

Let $F$ Be the non-empty finite bounded subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$. We want to know if $F$ is complete with respect to the Hausdorff metric.

I made a subset of all natural numbers in the interval $[0,10+1/n]$ this a subset of $F$, and we can construct the Cauchy sequence $G_n$ which converges (according to the Hausdorff metric) to the union of $B(x,\varepsilon)$ with $x \in $$\{0,1,2,..,10\}$ which is not a finite subset of  $\mathbb{R}^2$ and thus is $(F,h)$ not complete.

Is this correct? I do not know what I can do to complete this space because I find it very difficult to construct a row with the finite subsets if it can converge to a subset which is uncountable. Can anybody tell me if my first thought are correct and help me to complete this space?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unfortunately, what you wrote is incomprehensible. Try to write the question in your native language, maybe somebody here can translate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have realized that finite sets can converge to infinite sets in the Hausdorff metric. The natural question is to see how far this can be taken. Let $C \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ be a compact set. For each $p \in C$ construct the epsilon ball $B(\epsilon, p)$ centered at $p$. The collection of these balls cover $C$ and we can choose a finite subcover $\{B(\epsilon, p_1), \ldots, B(\epsilon, p_n)\}$. The set $\{p_1, \ldots, p_n\}$ is a finite set whose Hausdorff distance is within $\epsilon$ of $C$. By letting $\epsilon \to 0$ we obtain a sequence of finite subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ converging to $C$.

This suggests that the compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the Hausdorff distance  is a natural canidate for the space you are looking for. We only have to prove that it is complete. I have seen this theorem proved in section 1.5 of "Geometric Integration Theory" by Parks and Krantz. The book also discusses a lot of other useful properties of this metric space. The book is available publicly online at [https://www.math.wustl.edu/~sk/books/root.pdf](https://www.math.wustl.edu/%7Esk/books/root.pdf)